# Создаю блог с новостями, при добавлении картинок они дублируются под каждым объектом

Tags: python, django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

# Create your models here.

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

        return self.name


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "//" % (self.id)
```

views.py

```
from django.views import generic

from .models import Articles


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "news/posts.html"
    context_object_name = 'articles_list'


    def get_queryset(self ):
        return Articles.objects.all()
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from RapterGames import settings
from . models import Articles

urlpatterns=[
    path('', ListView.as_view(queryset=Articles.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:20],template_name="news/posts.html")),
    path('<int:pk/>', DetailView.as_view(model=Articles, template_name="news/post.html"))
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

posts.html

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% for post in object_list %}

    {% for articles in articles_list  %}

        <p><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ articles.img.url }}"/></p>

    {% endfor %}


        <a href="/news/{{post.id}}"> <h3> {{post.title}} </h3> </a>

        <h5>{{post.date|date:"d-m-Y"}}</h5>

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Логично так так происходит. В `django.views.generic.ListView` при использовании в template к queryset можно обратиться с помощью **object_list**. У вас дополнительно во view параметр задан **context_object_name**  таким образом у вас в template вложенный цикл по одним и тем же объектам. Исправьте ваш posts.html

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% for article in articles_list  %}

        <p><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ article.img.url }}"/></p>

        <a href="/news/{{article.id}}"> <h3> {{article.title}} </h3> </a>

        <h5>{{article.date|date:"d-m-Y"}}</h5>

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```